# VBA - Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Tags: vba, excel

I get that error on this line

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BT & HighPeriod, :BT" & lastRow), _
    Type:=xlFillDefault
```

`HighPeriod` is an integer. Is it possible to use integers in both values of the Range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there's a typo in your code, you might want to test with:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BT" & HighPeriod & ":BT" & lastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

or

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BT" & HighPeriod, "BT" & lastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

if you're sure about the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tested your suggestions, unfortunately I get the same error. This original line works: Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BT119:BT" & lastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault,    I'm trying to make the program more dynamic by replacing "119" with "HighPeriod". "119" is used at a lot of places in the program. Any more ideas? Best regards, Daniel

Comment: @vighurt if the code works with 119, then you have just fixed the problem of syntax I told you and highlighted a new one. We cannot help you if you dont show us _how_ you define the variable HighPeriod

Comment: It's solved! Had to add HighPeriod+1. Thanks again and have a great weekend! /Daniel